# Postman pre-request script iterate over request body JSON

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

I am sending raw POST request with application/json data to server in Postman. I need to work with this JSON object and append some data in pre-request script. However I can only find how to access environmental variables, not request body. Anybody knows, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"I can only find how to access environmental variables, not request body"*

You can access request body in Pre-request Script via `pm.request.body`.

Unfortunately, you cannot change it through script (at least not supported in Jul. 2018). Please check this [thread](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4808) for some previous discussion.

However, there is a workaround: you can make the whole request body use environment variable, such as `{{reqBody}}`, and edit that variable in Pre-request Script panel. For example:

```
var defaultReqBody = {
  a: 42
};
//Edit defaultReqBody ...
pm.environment.set("reqBody", JSON.stringify(defaultReqBody));
```